# Can't remove Remote Connection in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-connection, remoteapp

I am hoping this is a simple fix.

It seems that you can't remove a Remote Desktop Connection. In Windows 7, there was a "Remove" in the last area (indicated with a red box in my picture):

[image: Windows 10 Remoteapp and Desktop Connections]

Is it something that I am missing in Group Policy or is it something you can't do in Windows 10 or something completely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had the same problem (also on Windows 10) and solved it from here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/36d0849e-3002-4dd9-994d-cc0466d6b6bf/remove-old-rdweb-feed-from-windows-7-remoteapp-clients?forum=winserverTS

Basically just remove the feed from the registry by deleting it at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\workspaces\Feeds\` and delete it from appdata at `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Workspaces\`

Answer (score 0):

Warning - I deleted a RemoteApp connection by deleting the feed at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\workspaces\Feeds.  This broke something on the workstation, and now it can't connect to any RemoteApp connections.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.  You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).